# Where Is the Latest Mac OS Backing Store

Tags: macos, sqlite, core-data

I'm running Xcode 8.1 on Sierra 10.12.2 using Swift 3.0. I'm trying to find the sqlite database the Core Data writes to when it is serializes data. I've found several other questions here on the same subject. Since the location seems to move with every major release, they are out of data. Also, they address iOS simulators. Presumably,I'm not using one when running Mac OS code on Mac OS.I tried doing a find on *.sqlite. I got a lot of matches. None one them looked like they were for my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, and with the toolchain you describe, the template is set to:

```
~/Library/Application Support/com.apple.toolsQA.CocoaApp_CD/swift_cd.storedata
```

You can edit this in `AppDelegate.swift`. See the lazily instantiated var: **applicationDocumentsDirectory**.

Comment: That worked. It appears to be an XML file. Is there an option to save it as sqlite?

Comment: See var coordinator. Alter the line "try coordinator!.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSXMLStoreType..." to "try coordinator!.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType..."